# RH/CentOS service & chkconfig equivalents in Ubuntu/Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, service, init.d

In RedHat/CentOS distros, you start and stop services with `/sbin/service`:

```
/sbin/service httpd reload
```

You set whether they should run on startup with `/sbin/chkconfig`:

```
/sbin/chkconfig --levels 2345 on
```

What are the equivalents for a Debian-based distro like Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Debian and Ubuntu you can run `/etc/init.d` scripts directly, as used to be true also on Red Hat / Centos, or use `invoke-rc.d` or `service`.  I think the `upstart` stuff is still evolving, so this may change.

```
# /etc/init.d/httpd reload
# /usr/bin/service httpd reload
# /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d httpd reload
```

`update-rc.d` is the tool corresponding to `chkconfig`.

```
# /usr/sbin/update-rc.d httpd start 20 2 3 4 5 . 80 0 1 6 .
```

But `insserv` is becoming the standard way to do this:

```
 # /sbin/insserv httpd,start=2,3,4,5 # 0,1,6 will be automatically set to off
```

Comment: You still can run init.d scripts directly in RedHat/Centos.

Answer (score 3):

Services can be started/stopped in Ubuntu with `/usr/sbin/service serviceName start|stop`.  The syntax is the same as RH/Cent, but the path is different.  Upstart isn't currently used in Debian, so use `/etc/init.d/service serviceName start|stop` instead.

`/usr/sbin/update-rc.d` is what I use to enable/disable services at startup.  Check out the manpage for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu releases which use upstart, many services don't have /etc/init.d scripts.  The utility to use in this case is *initctl*

Here's a link describing it and Upstart in general.

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#utilities